# Fluentd record transformer conditional statements to add key if not present

Tags: ruby, parsing, fluentd

I want to add a message field to the log if it is not present in the logs.

Here's the relevant fluentd configuration:

```xml
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    message ${ if record.has_key?('message'); then record ["message"]; else record["message"] == "nomsg"; end}
  </record>
</filter>
```

But when the message field is not present I get `message=false`, when it is present getting `message=actual_msg`.

Not sure why it is not taking `message=nomsg`.

Please help and suggest.
Tried above syntax to and fro but no luck.

Comment: Try: `message ${ if record.has_key?('message'); then record['message']; else 'nomsg'; end }`

Comment: In the `else` part i.e. `record["message"] == "nomsg"`, it's a Boolean comparison that's why you're getting `false`. Your objective is to get `nomsg` so you'll simply return that.

Comment: This could be simplified i.e. `message ${ record['message'] || 'nomsg'  }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make changes in `else` condition as below:

```
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    message ${ if record.has_key?('message'); then record ["message"]; else "nomsg"; end}
  </record>
</filter>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I added msg field as well like message ${ record ["message"] || record ["msg"] || "no log message"] and it is working perfectly on local with td-agent. Thank you once again 